# SerialPort C# incorrect byte in frame

Tags: c#, serial-port, microcontroller

I have designed program in C# that speaks to a microcontroller by UART ( There is FT232 between).

I have improved my application to send/calculate and validate checksum.

I have the problem that randomly for some variables I get number 63 in a random position of my byte frame. Only when data is sent back from the microcontroller to PC.
I have checked it and in microcontrollers send buffer everything is fine but it comes to PC with 63 in one place. Not for every variable, I send. It is about 40 of them, and only 8 gets faulty with that 63 number.

My UART Baud rate is 921600.  Maybe it is too fast?

Has anybody had experience with that fault?

Best regards,
Chris

Comment: Try to use slower baudrate and default setting like 9600,8,N,1

Comment: 63 == '?'.  You get a question mark when you read binary data with a string method like ReadExisting().  Byte values >= 128 don't have a corresponding ASCII character so produce ?.  Use Read() instead.